# Cannot remove entry from Articles & Blogs section

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I came across what appears to be a bug while editing my resume on Careers. I tested in Firefox 46.0.1 as well as Microsoft Edge 25.10586.0.0 with identical result.

To reproduce, go to "Jobs" tab from Stack Overflow, then click the small "edit cv" tab near the top. Then scroll down to "Articles & Blogs" section, and see screenshot:

[image: remove-article]

After selecting this, and confirming in the next menu, the entry is not removed. Refreshing the page made no difference. I also tried to remove it from the "edit" menu and that also did not work.

---

#### Workaround

I found a workaround which achieves the result of removing an entry, but still not working as it should. I had to edit an entry, and then delete the name, URL etc. all the text fields then save it. It still left the icon there, but after I refreshed and went back to my CV it was now gone.

Comment: Reproduced on Chrome 50.0.2661.102 on Windows 7 Enterprise. I also get a `jquery.js:9664 POST http://stackoverflow.com/jobs/cv/article/remove/107795 404 (Not Found)` error logged in the Developer Console when I click on remove.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this! This should be fixed now. :)

Comment: I confirmed the fix works, thank you!