# Can't delete old blog posts from careers profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I had some old blog posts in the "writings" section of my careers profile that I added 5 years ago. They weren't very good samples of my current work, so I tried to delete them. However, they couldn't be deleted. I found that some errors were being printed to the console saying that no article existed with the ID being sent to the server.
In order to get the links to stop showing, I ended up deleting the title, description, date, link, etc. and they stopped showing in the web view. However, when I try to generate a PDF version of my CV they are still there, showing as just links with no descriptions or titles. I can't use the generated PDF with those links on there. Can someone help me remove them?
(I sent an email about resolving this issue and was redirected here; the help ID was 201605301255262524.)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for reporting this. Another user also had this problem so this should be fixed now. [Cannot remove entry from Articles & Blogs section](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323639/cannot-remove-entry-from-articles-blogs-section/324446#324446).

**Update**

The above fixed the inability to delete a blog/article, however this was a slightly different bug, which occurred when a user edited and cleared out the fields instead of deleting the post. These articles/blog posts should now show up on your Edit CV page and be editable and deletable.

Comment: Nope, the articles still show up in the generated PDF.